# How to get date format in underscore js while rendering template?

Tags: symfony, twig, underscore.js

I'm using the `underscore.js` templating function and have done a template like this:

```
<span class="msg-date"><% if (typeof(sent_date) != "undefined"){ %>
    <%= format(sent_date, 'd-m-Y') %><% } %>
</span>
<span class="msg-time"><% if (sent_date){ %><%= sent_date %><% } %></span>
```

As you can see I have add a format to `sent_date` in format of `d-m-Y`. But I can't get correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format` doesn't format dates in twig. It's basically the same as `printf()`.

To format the date you want to use the `date` modifier:

`sent_date|date('d-m-Y')`

Comment: I apologize, I was thinking of this from a TWIG point of view. Not underscore.js. What output are you actually getting from your template?

Comment: Please give ans from underscore.js view

Answer (score 2):

There is no special date modifiers in underscore.js template() function. To format your date u can use any other third party lib for this or javascript Date object. For more details and options see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) answer.

Comment: gee, underscore is really lame